# How can I make caff work with msmtp?

Tags: gnupg

I've a working msmtp configuration and I would like caff (from signing-party package) to use msmtp to send the keys I sign after a KSP. So far I'm only getting this error message:

```
No real MTA found, using ‘testfile’ at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/Mailer.pm line
108.
```

Have somebody use caff with msmtp???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing comes from the PERL
[Mail::Mailer](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/MailTools-2.07/)
package.  Although Mail::Mailer supports sending e-mail directly with
SMTP (thus, no `sendmail` binary needed), it defaults to using
`sendmail` on Linux/UNIX and the only way to change that is through
change of the constructor parameters in the sources.

So, I can see only three options:

1. Install an MTA that provides command-line `sendmail` emulation;
   package *msmtp-mta* provides that on top of *msmtp*; other MTAs
   like [esmtp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/8/esmtp) and
   [nullmailer](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/8/nullmailer) can also do
   this.
2. Provide your own `sendmail`-emulation script that pipes input to `msmtp`; you can then direct Mail::Mailer to use that instead of the system-wide sendmail (see [the Mail::Mailer doc](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/MailTools-2.07/lib/Mail/Mailer.pod#ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES) for details):

   ```
   export PERL_MAILERS="sendmail:/path/to/my/sendmail/wrapper"
   ```
3. Change the `caff` sources to create the Mail::Mailer object as:

   ```
   $mailer = Mail::Mailer->new('smtp', Server => 'smtp.server.example.org');
   ```

   instead of the default invocation that it is likely using now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it solved out after installing msmtp-mta package u_u

Comment: @alucardni thanks, I've updated the answer with your final resolution.